# How to sort grouped objects primarily by year and secondarily by month from timestamp?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have several objects instantiated from class **Invoice**.

Each has attribute **sorting_date** (timestamp).

I want to group all Invoices by ***year and month*** and display the months  in a list with the newest first and then the rest following in chronological order. Newest to oldest.

### What I want:

2019-February
2019-January
2018-December

### What I have:

2019-January
2018-December
2019-February

### My code:

```
$months = Invoice::where("user_id", $id)->pluck('sorting_date')->groupBy('month', 'year');
$months = $months->sortBy('year');
```

In tinker ***$months*** looks like this after the above operation (only months as keys):

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3069
     all: [
       1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3066
         all: [
           Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1546796483 {#3052
             date: 2019-01-06 17:41:23.0 UTC (+00:00),
           },
         ],
       },
       12 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3043
         all: [
           1 => Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1544118083 {#3060
             date: 2018-12-06 17:41:23.0 UTC (+00:00),
           },
         ],
       },
       2 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3040
         all: [
           2 => Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1549474883 {#3058
             date: 2019-02-06 17:41:23.0 UTC (+00:00),
           },
           3 => Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1549474883 {#3033
             date: 2019-02-06 17:41:23.0 UTC (+00:00),
           },
         ],
       },
     ],
   }
```

I understand that my code does not work. It doesn't matter what I write in the *sortBy('year')*. I can even write *sortBy('banana')* and gives me same result. It does not give an error but also not wished result. Even if it did it would just have sorted them by year. Inside that year the months could still be wrong.

Comment: I think you need to sortBy before pluck. Because the pluck will only keep the key `sorting_date`, so you can't sort by a key which doesn't exist.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to count the number of invoices for each month and ordered by descending order on the date?

Comment: @VincentDecaux but in sorting date all the info I need exists? As it is a full timestamp.

Comment: @Mozammil As the question states I want to list all months that has an invoice with a timestamp for said month. The list should also be sorted by year so eg 2018 January and 2019 January should be different list items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this in SQL. You don't have to manipulate your result set with Collections.

So, using Query Builder (or Eloquent), you can do something like this:

```
return DB::table('invoices')
    ->selectRaw('YEAR(sorting_date) AS year, MONTHNAME(sorting_date) month, COUNT(*)')
    ->groupby('year','month')
    ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
    ->orderByRaw('MONTH(sorting_date) DESC')
    ->get();
```

Here's an [example](https://implode.io/vDqjbT) that you can also play around with.